# Java reflection get sub class variable values / get object instance from member field

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have a class that has some member variables one or more being another class also with member variables. How can I get the value of each variable in both classes?

I can get the variables by calling: `getDeclaredFields();` And the values of the Foo Object by calling `field.get(obj)` then iterating of them again to get the sub class variables.

But how can I get the value for each sub class member variable without an instance of that class?
My trivial example works because the variables are the same for each instance of the `Bar` class and I can call `innerField.get(new Bar())`

I guess it could work if I could somehow get the instance of the object from the field?

Thanks in advance

*First Object:*

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(){}
    private Integer someInt = 123;
    private Long someLong = 987654321L;
    private String someString = "qwertyuiop";
    private Bar bar = new Bar();
}
```

*Second Object:*

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(){}
    private Double someDouble = 123.456;
    private String innerString = "another String";
}
```

*main/ calling method:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    getMemberFields(foo);
}
```

*Getting variables and values:*

```
public static void getMemberFields(Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException,               NoSuchFieldException {
    Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();
    System.out.println("obj: " + obj.getClass());

    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Field: " + field.getName() + " value: " + field.get(obj));

        Field[] innerFields = {};
        if (!field.getType().getName().contains("java.lang")) {
             innerFields = field.getType().getDeclaredFields();
        }

        for (Field innerField: innerFields) {
            if (!innerField.getName().contains("java.lang")) {
                Object subObj = field.getType();

                innerField.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.println("");

                System.out.println("Sub Field: " + innerField.getName());
                System.out.println( "Sub Field value: " + innerField.get(new Bar()));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
obj: class Foo
Field: someInt value: 123
Field: someLong value: 987654321
Field: someString value: qwertyuiop
Field: bar value: Bar@61bbe9ba
Sub Field: someDouble
Sub Field value: 123.456
Sub Field: innerString
Sub Field value: another String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was rather simple. 
If anyone else comes accross the same issue here's how I solved it.

```
private static HashMap<String, Object> getMemberFields(Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException,
        NoSuchFieldException
{
     HashMap<String, Object> fieldValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();

    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields)
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        fieldValues.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
        if (!field.getType().isPrimitive() && !field.getType().getName().contains("java.lang"))
        {
            getMemberFields(field.get(obj));
        }
    }
    return fieldValues;
}
```